# How to start default android lock screen from an app other than pressing the power button twice?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sleep, lockscreen

Is there an intent associated with lock screen so that I can start the lock screen from my app? or Any other way to start Lock screen from an app?. I tried to use goToSleep and wakeUp methods (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) so that, I can force the lock screen. But the app doesn't have permission for DEVICE_POWER (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER). Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

**1) Add this intent in your onCreate to provide Device_Admin permission**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager  
                    .ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);  
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,  
                    compName);  
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,  
                    "");  
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
```

**2) Add receiver class in manifest:**

```
 <receiver
                android:name="com.example.AdminReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                    android:resource="@layout/policies" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" >
                        </action>
                    </intent-filter>
                </meta-data>
            </receiver>
```

**3) Add Receiver class extending DeviceAdminReceiver**

```
    public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver{  


        static SharedPreferences getSamplePreferences(Context context) {  
            return context.getSharedPreferences(  
              DeviceAdminReceiver.class.getName(), 0);  
        }  
 }
```

**4) Add XML file (policies.xml) in layout folder**

```
<!-- ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? -->
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password>
            <watch-login>
                <reset-password>
                    <force-lock>
                        <wipe-data>
                        </wipe-data>
                    </force-lock>
                </reset-password>
            </watch-login>
        </limit-password>
    </uses-policies>

</device-admin>
```

Comment: Do you just want to lock the phone screen on start of your application? I am just not getting your question correctly.

Comment: I have an activity running in my app.  Now when I press a button in that activity, I need to lock the screen. Simple as that. But I can't find a solution.

Comment: @John Please have a look on above edited solution. find bug, Come again